# Forms not updating accordingly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my form to update specific records withing my db.

I have en editing page to edit the record and have now added a upload form for documents for that specific record but when it uploads it only creates a new row with the captured data i.e. the file name and the uploaded file is correctly placed, just not under the relevant record.

I got it working!

The table where the waning upload form is on:

```
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="includes/add.php?ID=<?php echo "$idnumber" ?>" method="POST"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="idenumber" value="<?php echo $idnumber; ?>"/>
 <th>Ad Warnings Documents</th>
 <tr>
 <td>Warning File 1</td>
 <td><input type="file" name="warning1" value="<?php echo $warning1;?>" /></td>

 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Warning File 2</td>
 <td><input type="file" name="warning2" value="<?php echo $warning2;?>" ></td>

 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Warning File 3</td>
 <td><input type="file" name="warning3" value="<?php echo $warning3;?>">

</td>
 </tr>

  <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Add"> </td></tr>
 </table>
```

The final working upload script

```
        <?php
    include 'core/init.php';
     // Connects to your Database 
    include 'includes/overall/header.php';
    error_reporting(1);
    $idnumber = 'idnumber';
    $connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection problems.';
    mysql_connect('localhost', '', '') or die($connect_error);
    mysql_select_db('') or die($connect_error);
   $query= "SELECT idnumber FROM ref_employees WHERE  $idnumber = `idnumber`" or die($connect_error);

     $idnumber=$_POST['idnumber'] ;
      //This is the directory where images will be saved 
    $target = "../files/empdocs/"; 
    $target1 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning1']['name']); 
    $target2 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning2']['name']);
    $target3 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning3']['name']);
     //This gets all the other information from the form 


     $warning1=($_FILES['warning1']['name']); 
     $warning2=($_FILES['warning2']['name']);
     $warning3=($_FILES['warning3']['name']); 


      //Writes the information to the database 
  $q = "UPDATE ref_employees SET `warning1` = '$warning1',
                               `warning2` = '$warning2',
                               `warning3` = '$warning3'
         WHERE $idnumber=`idnumber`";
$res = mysql_query( $q );
if ( ! $res ) {
    // an error occured
}
      //Writes the file to the server 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning1']['tmp_name'], $target1))
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['warning1']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning2']['tmp_name'], $target2))
     echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['warning2']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning3']['tmp_name'], $target3))
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['warning3']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
     //Tells you if its all ok 

     else { 

     //Gives and error if its not 
     echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 

     }
     ?>

     <?php
    include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Thanks for everyone for your help and guidance.

Comment: If you are editing, you want to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Also, **stay the hell away from w3schools**.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Teresko. I have gotten it to update only when using the update query with the physical 'idnumber', dont know where I am going wrong but seems people like to depreciate so I'd rather leave it at that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
mysql_query("UPDATE ref_employees 
  SET `warning1`='$warning1',`warning2`='$warning2',`warning3`='$warning3' 
  WHERE `idnumber`='$idnumber'"
  ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: With the update no row is captured, I update the 2 pages that I am using

Comment: The second form is the headache

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If no rows were _updated_, that could only mean that there's no row with `idnumber='idnumber'`. Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: What sample data do you require?

Comment: Your table's of course, including the `idnumber` field, to cross-check if a corresponding value is there or not.

Comment: And what's the idnumber you are supplying?

Comment: Well the current record I am trying to edit is under 8603115065081

Comment: It sure does thank you. Although not through $idnumber but only if I specify the number itself?

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to include the idnumber in the INSERT sql.

```
//Writes the information to the database 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ref_employees (`idnumber`, `warning1`,`warning2`,`warning3`) 
                    VALUES ('$idnumber','$warning1', '$warning2', '$warning3')")  or die(mysql_error());
```

Or if the row already exists in the table and you just want to add this information to an existing row you need to do an update

```
$q = "UPDATE ref_employees SET `warning1` = '$warning1',
                               `warning2` = '$warning2',
                               `warning3` = '$warning3'
         WHERE `idnumber` = '$idnumber'";
$res = mysql_query( $q );
if ( ! $res ) {
    // an error occured
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to update an existing row in the table with the 3 warning fields? If so I have added to my answer.

Comment: Still the file is being uploaded bu with no entry into the db